# Refraction quality is lower in rendered image than in the viewport preview

Tags: rendering, glass

I was playing around with Glass BSDF shader to see what it look like and how it interacts with its environment. Bellow, you can see a test scene.

Preview[image: test render of a cube sphere and suzanne]

Final [image]
  The preview render on the sphere looks fine but when a final render was done the refraction of the checker-board was pixelated and distorted. The final render was done with 400 samples. Is that too little or am I missing something.
Is there a way to improve render quality of the refraction in the glass sphere?

File here : [image]

Comment: Are you using flat shading on the sphere and suzanne? Can you upload the scene, e.g. on pasteall.org?

Comment: @B.Y.O.B. here is the url http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49181
Sorry, new to this and not sure what you mean by flat shading.

Comment: @B.Y.O.B. in pasteall the links expire after a few months. For permanent links use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Select the sphere, go into edit mode (Tab), press W, click "Shade Smooth" and render again. @cegaton Good point.
 edit: looking at the .blend, the subsurf modifier is set to 4 in viewport and 2 in render, that's why it looks ok in viewport (the high subdivision hides the flat shading)

Comment: @B.Y.O.B. thank you, it worked. I will edit the port with a permanent link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using flat shading on the mesh, as opposed to smooth shading that interpolates normals: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html?highlight=smooth%20shading#shading

The reason why it looks ok in the viewport is that your subdivision surface modifier is set to 4 iterations for the viewport and 2 iterations for the final render. So the high subdivision in the viewport hides the flat shading.

Solution: Set viewport subdivisions equal or lower than final subdivisions, and enable smooth shading on the mesh (see above link).